# Grid ASCII art code golf

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, grid

## Challenge

Create the shortest program that meets the requirements

### Requirements

1. The code must generate a 5x5 grid of 0s, like so:

   ```
   00000
   00000
   00000
   00000
   00000
   ```
2. The code must accept an input (column, row, character). The grid must change accordingly:

   Start:

   ```
   00000
   00000
   00000
   00000
   00000
   ```

   Input:

   ```
   (2,5,*)
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   0*000
   00000
   00000
   00000
   00000
   ```

   (Note: the bottom-left corner is position 1,1.)
3. The program must return an error message other than the grid if the row/column input is not 1,2,3,4, or 5. This can be any message of your choice (as long as it's not the grid), so `0` is an acceptable error-output.
4. The program must work with all printable ASCII characters (of a US keyboard).

### THE WINNER

The winner will be the person who has the shortest code and fulfills all requirements. If more than one answer works and has the same (shortest) length, the person who answered first will be the winner.

Comment: _The program must return an error message_. What error message? Can the program return `0` for error and the grid for success?

Comment: That is a great idea. By an error message I meant something that tells the user that their input was invalid, but your idea would work just fine.

Comment: Where is the origin on the matrix? does it need to be zero or one indexed?

Comment: The bottom most left corner is (1,1).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, by the way.

Comment: _he program must work with all characters on the US keyboard_ Why not just ASCII? I do not even know the characters of a US keyboard, and that doesn't add anything to the challenge

Comment: @LuisMendo I think the US keyboard is ASCII, or is at least a subset.

Comment: I will disregard the US keyboard requirement.

Comment: _The program must return an error message if the row/column input is greater than 5_ I suppose we must also throw an error for values lower than 1. But could you please edit your question to clarify this point?

Comment: @DaveJones Wouldn't *if the row/column input is not 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5* be better?

Comment: yes. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Does it matter how we output the grid as long is it is correct and errors on bad input?

Comment: no, the method of output is arbitrary as long as it fulfills the specifications of the challenge

Comment: @ConorO'Brien  My keyboard has F1-F12 and arrow keys (whick generates multi character escape sequences) and Print Screen (which generates something that is NOT an ASCII character) - so it is a superset of ASCII.  I think we have to disregard the US keyboard requirement - otherwise my program actually needs to detect that the Print Screen or Pause key has been pressed and then which character should it stick in the grid?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah but those aren't _characters_ on the US keyboard.

Comment: Wow, Turtlèd is going to have a good time here...

Comment: As I said above, if you need to, you can disregard the US keyboard requirement as long as it works for all ascii characters

Comment: Question says 'the code must generate a 5x5 grid of 0s', does that mean we need to output both the starting grid and the altered grid, or only the final grid?

Comment: You only need to output the final grid.

Comment: -1 Because of the [cumbersome I/O format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/61384).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>17</s> <s>13</s> 10 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Prompts for an enclosed array containing (row, column) and then for a character. Gives INDEX ERROR on faulty input.

```apl
⊖⍞@⎕⊢5 5⍴0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdvSgz5f@jrmmPeuc5POqb@qhrkamC6aPeLQYgyf8KYABSw/Woq8lIwZRLCwA)

`⊖` flip upside-down the result of

`⍞` inputted-character

`@` replacing the content **at** position

`⎕` evaluated-input (enclosed row, column)

`⊢` of

`5 5⍴` 5×5 array of

`0` zeros

Comment: Is `⊢` necessary? I think in this case it's redundant.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien @ConorO'Brien if it isn't there, the parser sees `(⊂⎕)5 5` as a single 3-element array – the argument to `⍴`.

Comment: That is 13 Unicode characters, not 13 bytes, isn't it?

Comment: @wilx Click on the word [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)!

Comment: This answer is the winner.

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby, <s>157</s> 149 bytes

```
g=(1..5).map{[0]*5}
loop{puts g.map(&:join).join ?\n
x=gets.match /\((.),(.),(.)\)/
a,b=x[1].hex,x[2].hex
1/0 if a<1||a>5||b<1||b>5
g[5-b][a-1]=x[3]}
```

Error on malformed input or out of bound position

Thanks to ConorO'Brien (8 bytes) and afuous (2 bytes) for helping saving bytes

Comment: `loop do...end` -> `loop{...}`; I think `Array.new(5,[0]*5)` works, too, or even `[*[0]*5]*5`.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Nope, `Array.new(5,[0]*5)` make an array of reference and `[*[0]*5]*5` make a flat array

Comment: Oh, right. Omit the first `*`. Then that still creates an array of references.

Comment: `Array.new(5){[0]*5}` can be replaced with `(1..5).map{[0]*5}` to save 2 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, 199 bytes

```
@echo off
if %1 gtr 0 if %1 lss 6 if %2 gtr 0 if %2 lss 6 goto g
if
:g
for /l %%j in (5,1,-1)do call:l %* %%j
exit/b
:l
set s=000000
if %2==%2 call set s=%%s:~0,%1%%%3%%s:~%1%%
echo %s:~1,5%
```

Errors out if the position is out of range.

Comment: I think you can use symbols for `<`, like `^<`. not sure tho.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>111</s> <s>100</s> 97 bytes

```
$s=str_repeat("00000\n",5);$s[($x=($a=$argv)[1])+29-6*$y=$a[2]]=$a[3];echo$x&&$y&&$x<6&$y<6?$s:E;
```

prints `E` if row/column out of range.
Run with `php -r <code> <row> <column> <character>`

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 66 bytes

```
lambda a,b,n,l='00000\n':6>b>0<a<6and(5-b)*l+l[:a-1]+n+l[a:]+~-b*l
```

Comment: Won´t this fail for a=4,b=3?

Comment: @Titus not anymore ;D

Comment: Solution also works for Python3

Answer (score 3):

## Dyalog APL, <s>24</s> <s>20</s> 18 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to Zgarb! Saved 2 bytes thanks to Adam!

```
a←5 5⍴0⋄a[⊂⎕]←⍞⋄⊖a
```

Prompts for input. See below for an explanation.

---

### 20 bytes

```
{a←5 5⍴0⋄a[⊂⍺]←⍵⋄⊖a}
```

Assign to a function and call it `y x f 'c'`. E.g.:

```
      f←{a←5 5⍴0⋄a[⊂⍺]←⍵⋄⊖a}

      5 2 f '*'
0 * 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0

      6 6 f '*'
INDEX ERROR                   
     ←{a←5 5⍴0 ⋄ a[⊂⍺]←⍵ ⋄ ⊖a}
               ∧              

      0 0 f '*'
INDEX ERROR                   
     ←{a←5 5⍴0 ⋄ a[⊂⍺]←⍵ ⋄ ⊖a}
               ∧
```

### Explanation

```
{a←5 5⍴0⋄a[⊂⍺]←⍵⋄⊖a}
```

`{...}` is a function with left argument `⍺` and right argument `⍵`. `⋄` separates statements, so there are three statements:

```
a←5 5⍴0⋄a[⊂⍺]←⍵⋄⊖a
```

The first statement `a←5 5⍴0` sets `a` to a `5` by `5` grid of `0`s.

The second statement sets the member at coordinates dictated by `⍺` to `⍵` (that is, the character).

Finally, we perform `⊖` on `a` and return that, yielding the firsts of `a` reversed.

Comment: `{a←5 5⍴0⋄a[⊂⌽⍺]←⍵⋄⊖a}` saves a few bytes.

Comment: @Zgarb Oh, fantastic! I didn't know indexing worked like that.

Comment: You can save two bytes by converting to a tradfn body: `a←5 5⍴0⋄a[⊂⎕]←⍞⋄⊖a`

Comment: @Adám how does that work? It doesn't seem to work on TryAPL.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Right. TryAPL prohibits prompting for input, but you [can get](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM) the full version for free.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>73</s> 76 bytes

Throws a `TypeError` if the column or the row is out of range.

```js
(c,r,C,a=[...`00000
`.repeat(5)])=>(a[29+c-r*6]=C,c<1|r<1|c>5|r>5||a).join``
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

(c,r,C,a=[...`00000
`.repeat(5)])=>(a[29+c-r*6]=C,c<1|r<1|c>5|r>5||a).join``

console.log(f(2,5,'*'));
```

Comment: Sweet, but does it throw an error if either `c` or `r` is less than 1?

Comment: @ETHproductions It's only testing `c == 0 || r == 0`. But I guess you're right: I will update it to prevent negative values.

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 199 Bytes

Based on Pete Arden's answer

```
string g(int c, int r, char a){if(c<1|c>5|r<1|r>5)return "Index Error";var b="00000";var d=new[]{b,b,b,b,b};c--;d[r-1]=new string('0',c)+a+new string('0',4-c);return string.Join("\r\n",d.Reverse());}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public static string G(int c, int r, char a)
    {
        if (c < 1 || c > 5 || r < 1 || r > 5) return "Index Error"; // Check it's not out of range
        var b = "00000";
        var d = new [] { b, b, b, b, b };                           // Generate display box, and fill with the default character
        c--;                                                        // Convert the X to a 0 based index
        d[r - 1] = new string('0',c) + a + new string('0',4-c);     // Replace the array's entry in y coordinate with a new string containing the new character
        return string.Join("\r\n", d.Reverse());                    // Reverse the array (so it's the right way up), then convert to a single string
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm not an expert in C#, but it looks like there's some whitespace you could remove.

Comment: (Sorry, don't know submission etiquette) Shorter G(): public static string G(int c,int r,char a){return(0<c&&c<6&&0<r&&r<6)?string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(1,29).Select(i=>i%6>0?i/6==5-r&&i%6==c?a:'0':'\n')):"Index Error";}

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 28 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

This feels way too long...

```
Ṫ0ẋ24¤;ṙÑs5UY
’ḅ5
Ṗḟ5R¤
-ÑÇ?
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmqMOG6izI0wqQ74bmZw5FzNVVZCuKAmeG4hTUK4bmW4bifNVLCpAotw5HDhz8&input=&args=WzUsMiwnKidd)**

#### How?

```
Ṫ0ẋ24¤;ṙÑs5UY - Link 1, make grid: [row, column, character] e.g. [5,2,'*']
Ṫ             - tail: character                                  '*'
     ¤        - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad  
 0            -     zero
  ẋ           -     repeated
   24         -     24 times                                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
      ;       - concatenate:                                     "000000000000000000000000*"
        Ñ     - call next link (2) as a monad                    21
       ṙ      - rotate left by                                   "000*000000000000000000000"
         s5   - split into chunks of length 5                    ["000*0","00000","00000","00000","00000"]
           U  - upend (reveres each)                             ["0*000","00000","00000","00000","00000"]
            Y - join with line feeds                              0*000
              - implicit print                                    00000
                                                                  00000
’ḅ5 - Link 2, position: [row, column]                             00000
’   - decrement                                                   00000
 ḅ5 - convert from base 5

Ṗḟ5R¤ - Link 3, input error checking: [row, column, character]
Ṗ     - pop: [row, column]
 ḟ    - filter out values in
  5R¤ - range(5): [1,2,3,4,5] - any values not in this remain giving a truthy result

-ÑÇ? - Main link: [row, column, character]
   ? - ternary if:
  Ç  -    last link (3) as a monad
-    -    -1 (if truthy - the error identification)
 Ñ   - next link (1) as a monad (if falsey - the grid)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>27</s> 22 bytes

Returns no grid when row/column > 5.

```
‚6‹Pi25L²<5*¹+Q5äR»1³‡
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCaNuKAuVBpMjVMwrI8NSrCuStRNcOkUsK7McKz4oCh&input=Mgo1Cio)

**Previous version**

```
‚6‹Pi26G¾5²<*¹+NQi\³}})5äR»
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 89 bytes

```
f=(X,Y,Z,x=5,y=5)=>x+y>1?(x?X+x-6|Y-y?0:Z:`
`)+f(X,Y,Z,x?x-1:5,y-!x):X<1|X>5|Y<1|Y>5?e:""
```

Because I love recursion. Throws a `ReferenceError` on invalid coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel VBA, 67 Bytes

Outputs to the range *A1:E5* on the activesheet of the vba project, exits with

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Application-defined or object-defined error

when an invalid input is provided.

**Code:**

```vb
Sub a(c,r,x)
c=IIf(r<1Or c>5,-1,c)
[A1:E5]=0
Cells(6-r,c)=x
End Sub
```

**Usage:**

```vb
a 4,5,"#"
```

**Output** (from example above)**:**

```vb
    A   B   C   D   E
1   0   0   0   #   0
2   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 2):

**Mathematica, 38 bytes**

```
(x=Table[0,5,5];x[[-#2,#]]=#3;Grid@x)&
```

Answer (score 2):

## Brain-Flak 415 Bytes

Includes +3 for `-c`

```
([][()()()]){{}}{}({}<(({}<(({})<>)<>>)<>)<>([((((()()()){}){}){}){}]{}<([((((()()()){}){}){}){}]{})>)(()()()()()){({}[()]<(({})){{}(<({}[()])>)}{}({}<(({})){{}(<({}[()])>)}{}>)>)}{}({}{}){<>{{}}<>{}}<>>)<>(()()()()()){({}[()]<(((((((((()()()){}){}){}){})))))((()()()()()){})>)}{}{}<>({}<()((((((()()()){}){}()){}){}()[{}])({})({})({})({}){}{}[((((()()()){}){}){}){}()]){({}[()]<<>({}<>)>)}{}<>{}>)<>{({}<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it Online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KFtdWygpKCkoKV0pe3t9fXt9KHt9PCgoe308KCh7fSk8Pik8Pj4pPD4pPD4oWygoKCgoKSgpKCkpe30pe30pe30pe31de308KFsoKCgoKCkoKSgpKXt9KXt9KXt9KXt9XXt9KT4pKCgpKCkoKSgpKCkpeyh7fVsoKV08KCh7fSkpe3t9KDwoe31bKCldKT4pfXt9KHt9PCgoe30pKXt7fSg8KHt9WygpXSk-KX17fT4pPil9e30oe317fSl7PD57e319PD57fX08Pj4pPD4oKCkoKSgpKCkoKSl7KHt9WygpXTwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKSgpKCkpe30pe30pe30pe30pKSkpKSgoKCkoKSgpKCkoKSl7fSk-KX17fXt9PD4oe308KCkoKCgoKCgoKSgpKCkpe30pe30oKSl7fSl7fSgpW3t9XSkoe30pKHt9KSh7fSkoe30pe317fVsoKCgoKCkoKSgpKXt9KXt9KXt9KXt9KCldKXsoe31bKCldPDw-KHt9PD4pPil9e308Pnt9Pik8Pnsoe308Pik8Pn08Pg&input=KjEz&args=LWM)

Takes the character to insert first, then the row then column without spaces.

Most of this is just error handling. Brain-Flak doesn't have a good way to check if values are in a range. For errors, it either outputs nothing, or just the character that was supposed to be inserted. Solving the actual problem only takes 211 bytes:

```
<>(()()()()()){({}[()]<(((((((((()()()){}){}){}){})))))((()()()()()){})>)}{}{}<>({}<()((((((()()()){}){}()){}){}()[{}])({})({})({})({}){}{}[((((()()()){}){}){}){}()]){({}[()]<<>({}<>)>)}{}<>{}>)<>{({}<>)<>}<>
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 208 Bytes

Golfed:

```
string G(int c,int r,char a){if(c<1||c>5||r<1||r>5)return"Index Error";var b="00000";var d=new string[]{b,b,b,b,b};d[r-1]=d[r-1].Substring(0,c-1)+a+d[r-1].Substring(c);return string.Join("\r\n",d.Reverse());}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public string G(int c, int r, char a)
{
  if (c < 1 || c > 5 || r < 1 || r > 5) return "Index Error";
  var b = "00000";
  var d = new string[] { b, b, b, b, b };
  d[r - 1] = d[r - 1].Substring(0, c - 1) + a + d[r - 1].Substring(c);
  return string.Join("\r\n", d.Reverse());
}
```

Testing:

```
Console.Write(G(6, 6, '*')); //Index Error

Console.Write(G(1, 4, '#'));

00000
#0000
00000
00000
00000

Console.Write(G(5, 5, '@'));

0000@
00000
00000
00000
00000

Console.Write(G(1, 1, '}'));

00000
00000
00000
00000
}0000
```

Comment: If `c` and/or `r` are out of bounds it will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` so you might be able to remove the first if statement though I haven't checked the specs properly for that. You can compile to a `Func<int, int, char, string>` to save bytes, I believe you need to add `using System.Linq;` in because of the `Reverse` call though I can't remember off the top of my head

Comment: Change `d[r - 1] = d[r - 1].Substring(0, c - 1) + a + d[r - 1].Substring(c);` to `d[--r] = d[r].Substring(0, c - 1) + a + d[r].Substring(c);` to save 4 bytes

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>53</s> 50 bytes

EDIT: Now that I know that I don't have to show the starting grid, I've swapped out the user inputs `_!_!_?` for command line parameters `::;`, saving 3 bytes.

```
[5|?@00000|]::;~(b>5)+(c>5)>1|_Xd\$LOCATE 6-c,b|?B
```

Original version: This halts between printing the 0-grid and taking the coordinates for the substitution, showing the 0-grid.

```
[5|?@00000|]_!_!_?~(b>5)+(c>5)>1|_Xd\$LOCATE 6-c,b|?B
```

Prints 5 strings of 5 `0`'s, asks user for 2 numerical inputs and 1 string input, checks if the numbers are < 5 and uses QBasic's `LOCATE` function to substitute the right character.

Answer (score 1):

## WinDbg, 95 bytes

```
j(0<(@$t0|@$t1))&(6>@$t0)&(6>@$t1)'f8<<16 L19 30;eb2000018+@$t0-@$t1*5 @$t2;da/c5 8<<16 L19';?0
```

Almost half of it just verifying the indexes are in range... Input is done by setting the psuedo-registers `$t0`, `$t1`, and `$t2` (where `$t2` holds the ascii value of the char to replace). For example, `(2,5,*)` like the example would be:

```
0:000> r$t0=2
0:000> r$t1=5
0:000> r$t2=2a
```

Prints `0` on error.

How it works:

```
j (0<(@$t0|@$t1)) & (6>@$t0) & (6>@$t1)  * If $t0 and $t1 are both positive and less than 6
'
    f 8<<16 L19 30;                      * Put 19 (0n25) '0's (ascii 30) at 2000000 (8<<16)
    eb 2000018+@$t0-@$t1*5 @$t2;         * Replace the specified cell with the new char
    da /c5 8<<16 L19                     * Print 19 (0n25) chars in rows of length 5
';
    ?0                                   * ...Else print 0
```

Sample Output:

```
0:000> r$t0=2
0:000> r$t1=5
0:000> r$t2=2a
0:000> j(0<(@$t0|@$t1))&(6>@$t0)&(6>@$t1)'f8<<16 L19 30;eb2000018+@$t0-@$t1*5 @$t2;da/c5 8<<16 L19';?0
Filled 0x19 bytes
02000000  "0*000"
02000005  "00000"
0200000a  "00000"
0200000f  "00000"
02000014  "00000"


0:000> r$t0=-2
0:000> j(0<(@$t0|@$t1))&(6>@$t0)&(6>@$t1)'f8<<16 L19 30;eb2000018+@$t0-@$t1*5 @$t2;da/c5 8<<16 L19';?0
Evaluate expression: 0 = 00000000


0:000> r$t0=4
0:000> r$t1=2
0:000> r$t2=23
0:000> j(0<(@$t0|@$t1))&(6>@$t0)&(6>@$t1)'f8<<16 L19 30;eb2000018+@$t0-@$t1*5 @$t2;da/c5 8<<16 L19';?0
Filled 0x19 bytes
02000000  "00000"
02000005  "00000"
0200000a  "00000"
0200000f  "000#0"
02000014  "00000"


0:000> r$t1=f
0:000> j(0<(@$t0|@$t1))&(6>@$t0)&(6>@$t1)'f8<<16 L19 30;eb2000018+@$t0-@$t1*5 @$t2;da/c5 8<<16 L19';?0
Evaluate expression: 0 = 00000000
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 77 bytes

```
r=[1..5]
(x#y)c|x>0,x<6,y>0,y<6=unlines[[last$'0':[c|i==x,j==6-y]|i<-r]|j<-r]
```

Usage example:

```
*Main> putStr $ (2#5) '*'
0*000
00000
00000
00000
00000
```

If `x` and `y` are within range, outer and inner loop through `[1..5]` and take the char `c` if it hits the given `x` and `y` and a `0` otherwise. If `x` or `y` is not in range, a `Non-exhaustive patterns` exception is raised.

Answer (score 1):

## Octave 49 bytes

```
@(c,r,s)char(accumarray([6-r c],s+0,[5 5],[],48))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 99 bytes

```
(i,j,k)->{int[]b=new int[]{60,60,60,60,60};int[][]a=new int[][]{b,b,b,b,b};a[i-1][5-j]=k;return a;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Vim, <s>60</s> <s>47</s> <s>42</s> 76 keystrokes

Input is in the format (on the first line):

```
25*
```

With the cursor starting at the beginning

```
"ax"bxx:if<C-r>a<1||<C-r>a>5||<C-r>b<1||<C-r>b>5
^
endif
6i0<ESC>Y5pG:norm <C-r>al<C-r>bkr<C-r>-
Hqqxjq5@qdd
```

If the input is invalid, then throws: `E492: Not an editor command: ^`

The cide that produces the output is only `42` bytes, but in order to create an error, my bytecount is drastically increased.

Comment: BTW I don't know how to create the error in Vim

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, 59 bytes

**Golfed**

```
printf '00000%0.s\n' {1..5}|sed "$1 s/./$3/$2"|grep -z "$3"
```

*$1*, *$2* - row, column, *$3* - replacement char, error is reported via exit code

**Test**

```
>./box 2 2 "*"
00000
0*000
00000
00000
00000
>echo $?
0

>./box 6 2 '*'     
>echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>194</s> 192 bytes

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){String r="";int i=0,j,z=new Byte(a[0]),y=new Byte(a[1]);for(;++i<6;r+="\n")for(j=0;++j<6;r+=6-i==y&j==z?a[2]:0);System.out.print(z>0&z<7&y>0&y<7?r:0);}}
```

[Try it here with correct input.](https://tio.run/##Vc2xDoIwGATgV2k6mFaEVBIZrI1P4MSIHf5AMa3SYikkhvDsFcPkdvkulzMwQep6ZU3zjFHboHwLtUK3eQgQdI0mpxvUgbakDF7bRyWBzltEXmDMW@fJukNasIPhSaIvBfeJwHeL6a8zgq1qNiVFqhOMaabeI7wGAtVR0h0x/8YkvUKVyzOjvPwMQXWZG0PWr6eBeMqXJcaYx1PcfwE)
[Try it here with incorrect input.](https://tio.run/##Tc29DoIwFAXgV2kYSCs/qQ6QWK4k7k6MyNBgMa2hkFIxxfDsFePidE@@nJOr@MyTYRRa3R7eS22F6Xgr0OU9WW5li@ZB3lDPpcaVNVLf64aT9y8iA0HAtg2SQGMVL6DFC52dFZjXtCGx@4d9Q1g3GMyiSBYZMxEEVx2QLymgm6qfZokEcKECWEpeH5ojJaxykxV9OjxtOm6fLV5ONFyKPHTbdUVemm9rXb331Od@9wE)

This would be **<s>116</s> 114 bytes** instead as function instead of full program:

```java
(a,b,c)->{String r="";for(int i=0,j;++i<6;r+="\n")for(j=0;++j<6;r+=b==6-i&a==j?c:0);return a>0&a<7&b>0&b<7?r:"0";}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##dY/BasMwEETv/opFB2PVshGFxhBZyRc0lx7bHlaKE6Q6spHlQAn@dldOTOmll1125rHMWLxi0fWNs8evWbc4DPCKxt0SAONC40@oGzgsJ8Bb8MadQWfRAWQLAIr9ylREakriGAIGo@EADiTMGTLFNC12t5X0khBx6vz9j5GcWZHnpt4In0vy4QhdPCt5VO1DVVJuCpOilHavt5wK34TRO8AdT7GuUhW3qqu93xJOxDSLJUU/qjamWMNcO3OES6yWPVK8fwLStdf3EJpL2Y2h7KMVWpe5UmfPDF4YkCdC783@5TiD6g83JdP8Aw)

**Explanation:**

```java
interface M{                  // Class
  static void main(String[]a){//  Mandatory main-method
    String r="";              //   Result-String, starting empty
    int i=0,j,                //   Index-integers
        z=new Byte(a[0]),     //   First input converted to integer
        y=new Byte(a[1]);     //   Second input converted to integer
    for(;++i<6;               //   Loop (1) from 1 to 6 (inclusive)
        r+="\n")              //     After every iteration: Append a new-line to the result
      for(j=0;++j<6;          //    Inner loop (2) from 1 to 6 (inclusive)
        r+=6-i==y             //     If the second input equals `6-1`,
           &j==z?             //     and the first input equals `j`:
            a[2]              //      Append the third input to the result-String
           :                  //     Else:
            0                 //      Append a zero to the result-String
      );                      //    End of inner loop (2)
                              //   End of inner loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
    System.out.print(         //   Print:
     z>0&z<7&y>0&y<7?         //    If the coordinates are valid (1-6):
      r                       //     Print the result `r`
     :                        //    Else:
      0);                     //     Print 0 as error instead
  }                           //  End of main-method
}                             // End of class
```